# Traefik ingress controller throws error 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I expose my nginx service through traefik ingress controller. Unfortunately, it results with 503 error.

```
$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx
$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80
```

My traefik ingress configuration following [this](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/user-guide/kubernetes/#name-based-routing) documentation.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: http
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that, I had to change `servicePort: http` to `servicePort: 80` and this fixed the problem.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
```